# In C++/Cython it possible to only declare relevant attributes to be visible in Python?

Tags: python, c++, cython

Say I have a .h file with the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        int Attribute1;
        int Attribute2;
        MyClass(){};
        virtual ~MyClass(){};
        virtual void Method1(string var1);
        virtual float Method2(float var2);
};
```

And a related .pyx file with:

```
cdef class PyClass:
    cdef MyClass *classptr
        [standard __cinit__ and __dealloc__ declarations ]
        cdef int Attribute1;
        def Method1(self, var1):
            self.classptr.Method1(var1)
```

... and pxd file with:

```
cdef extern from "mycode.h":
    cdef cppclass MyClass:
        MyClass() except +
        int Attribute1
        void Method1(string)
```

And I use a setup.py to create a .so library to import in a python module.

Note that even though MyClass::Method2 and MyClass::Attribute2 exist in c++, I don't mention them in Cython, so they won't be visible in the .so library. Maybe I did so because they're indirectly used by  MyClass::Method1(), or just because I don't plan to invoke them in the python code.

Is this a bad practice likely to cause a problem/weird behavior? 
If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

```
cdef class PyClass:
    cdef MyClass *classptr
    # ...
    cdef int Attribute1;
```

`Attribute1` doesn't do what you think. It's a separate value stored as part of `PyClass` and has nothing to do with the `Attribute1` in `classptr`. You probably want to write a property instead.

---

However, to answer your question:

Yes, it's fine for you to only wrap the specific functions you're interested in. Cython doesn't need to know all the details of your C++ classes - it only needs to know enough details to generate valid C++ code using them. A few quick examples of things it's useful to omit:

- Templates. For example `std::string` is really a template typedef, but it may not be necessarily for a Cython wrapper to know this, or for optional allocator template types, or for numeric template types which Cython doesn't really support.
- Complicated inheritance hierarchies: doesn't matter if the functions you care about actually come from a base-class. Just wrap the derived class you're using.
- Interfaces that return other classes - because then you'd need to wrap the second class (which might expose a third class...).

There really is no consequence beyond not being able to call the code you haven't wrapped from python. Cython's C++ support is (and will likely always be) somewhat incomplete and it's often necessary to give it a simplified C++ interface to get anything done.

Comment: Wow, this is going to spare me a lot of trouble! Thanks!